# How to select the parent of an element when the element is hovered

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I've been trying to change the style of the parent of an element when the element is hovered. For example

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="some-other-class"></div>
</div>
```

In this case when the class child is hovered.i want to change the background and other properties of the parent class.

Is it possible to do this using css operators or do I have to use javascript for this process?

Any help would be appreciated..:)

Comment: A work around https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/hh47td1j/

Comment: @carol thanks for giving me that alternative.it was very helpful :)

Comment: Glad to help @ShrikanthBuds